# How to convert characters of a string "One" into an Integer "1" in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have implemented an quiz application in swift 4.0. Here, user can enter his choice from  ("one" or "1") to ("four" or "4") .

If the user can provide his choice as an integer(Eg 1,2,3, or 4)then there is no issue.
but if he provide his choice as an alphabet characters (Eg "one","two", ..), then i am facing the issues while validating correct answer.

Kindly, could anyone help me, How to convert  word characters "one" into integer 1 etc..

thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Can you show us what you already did?

Answer (score 3):

You can use NumberFormatter in this way:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut
let number = formatter.number(from: "one hundred twenty-five")
print(number)  // print out 125
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter/1408845-number